# Monitoring directory using ReadDirectoryChangesW API

Tags: c, winapi, filenames, systems-programming, readdirectorychangesw

I am trying to monitor a directory `e:\test` using [ReadDirectoryChangesW](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365465%28VS.85%29.aspx) API.

**My Code :**

```
#define UNICODE
#define WIN32_WINNT 0x0500
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>


HANDLE hDir;


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    FILE_NOTIFY_INFORMATION fniDir;
    DWORD i = 0;

    hDir = CreateFile(_T("e:\\test"), GENERIC_READ , FILE_SHARE_READ, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS, NULL);

    ReadDirectoryChangesW(hDir, &fniDir, sizeof(fniDir), TRUE, FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_FILE_NAME, &i, NULL, NULL);
    while(TRUE)
    {


    if(i>0)
        wprintf(L"%s", fniDir.FileName);
    }

    CloseHandle(hDir);

    return 0;
}
```

I don't know what's wrong with my code as I haven't understood ReadDirectoryChangesW documentation completely, specially the `LPOVERLAPPED`  parameters.

When I run the code I don't get any output, except for a blank console window. Can someone point me in a right direction?

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You only need the overlapped struct if you plan on catching the changes notifications asynchronously. In your code you don't need it.

Here's how you do it.

```
HANDLE hDir = CreateFile( 
        p.string().c_str(), /* pointer to the file name */
        FILE_LIST_DIRECTORY,                /* (this is important to be FILE_LIST_DIRECTORY!) access (read-write) mode */
        FILE_SHARE_WRITE | FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_DELETE,  /* (file share write is needed, or else user is not able to rename file while you hold it) share mode */
        NULL, /* security descriptor */
        OPEN_EXISTING, /* how to create */
        FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS, /* file attributes */
        NULL /* file with attributes to copy */
        );

    if(hDir == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE){
        throw runtime_error(string("Could not open ").append(p.string()).append(" for watching!"));
    }

    FILE_NOTIFY_INFORMATION buffer[1024];
    DWORD BytesReturned;
    while( ReadDirectoryChangesW(
        hDir, /* handle to directory */
        &buffer, /* read results buffer */
        sizeof(buffer), /* length of buffer */
        TRUE, /* monitoring option */           
        FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_LAST_WRITE, /* filter conditions */
        &BytesReturned, /* bytes returned */
        NULL, /* overlapped buffer */
        NULL)){
            do{
                            //CANT DO THIS! FileName is NOT \0 terminated
                //wprintf("file: %s\n",buffer.FileName);
                            buffer += buffer.NextEntryOffset;
            }while(buffer.NextEntryOffset);
    }
```

Comment: +1 Thanks for your answer. I have few questions Why do we have to create array of `FILE_NOTIFY_INFORMATION` and what is `NextEntryOffset` does it mean that it contains the number of bytes to go to next record in the array?

Comment: @Searock One notification can contain more then one file that changed inside that directory. You don't get one notification per change but batches. The buffer there is because FILE_NOTIFIY_INFORMATION uses a "trick" it defines the filename as wchar[1] (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364391%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and then you are responsible for setting it to a size to fit the number of files you need.

Comment: The buffer iteration code is wrong. Each FILE_NOTIFY_INFORMATION struct member is variable length, so you cannot simply index into the array. You must calculate the distance to the next entry each time.

Also, the wprintf is wrong. FileName is not null terminated.

Comment: Your sample does not work. The best option is to have a buffer consisting of chars.
After reading it, set a pointer to its start, then also create FILE_NOTIFY_INFORMATION* to the latest pointer. Iteration then consists in setting the pointer to the current value and NextEntryOffset.